# Вернуть переменную ref из метода

Tags: c#, winforms

В классе `Func` есть метод:

```
public static void Test(ref string test)
{
    test = "тест";
}
```

На форме делаю так:

```
Func.Test(ref lbStatus.Text);
```

> **Получаю ошибку:** "Свойство, индексатор или динамический член не может передаваться как параметр с ключевым словом out или ref"

Пробовал так:

```
string test1;
Func.Test(ref test1);
```

> **Получаю ошибку:** "Использование локальной переменной "test1", которой не присвоено значение"

Собственно, как мне из метода, вернуть переменную `test` в `label`?

Comment: `string test1 = null; Func.Test(ref test1);`

Comment: @PetSerAl, спасибо, ваш вариант тоже рабочий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string test1;// Инициализацию надо сделать.Присвойте test1 = lbStatus.Text;
Func.Test(ref test1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.